# How can I get the permission to display all joined groups on facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to get all groups joined by a facebook user, but I can get only the permission to get managed groups.

The code I'm using to do this

```
$groups = $facebook->api( '/me/groups', 'GET', array( 'access_token=' => $access_token ) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `user_groups` permission is deprecated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

**There is no way to get all groups anymore**, you can only get the managed ones with `user_managed_groups`.